# Pine Script. Dynamic Stop Loss

Tags: pine-script

Idea: after opening a position, we remember the maximum candle readings and look for the maximum price after each new candle. Depending on the maximum price, we set a stop loss. For example, 25 points lower, but not higher than the closing price of the current candle. Please help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIA4P.jpg)

Comment: This isn't an indicator-writing service. It's a forum where Pine coders help each other resolve coding challenges, which usually entails they have code to show where they are stuck.

Comment: I actually wrote the code, but it did not give any results. The idea of solving this problem is that we remember the previous maximum value of the candle and compare it with the current one, but to start doing this, we need to define the 'maxPrice' variable with the minimum value outside the loop. In fact, our entire script is a loop (if I understand correctly, then every new candle, or every tick, our script runs completely), so if we define a variable with a minimum value, and then change it, then the next candle or tick, our variable will reset again and we will lose the value, right?

Comment: The second option: you can set a condition that the variable is not defined in the first iteration, that is, something like if (maxPrice == null) as for example in Java. This seems logical, but unfortunately I haven't found an alternative in Pine Script yet. Logically writing a search for the maximum value is not difficult, but in this language, unfortunately, I can't think of a way to get around this problem.
Correct me if I'm wrong about something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for details on [Pine's execution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html).

Note how [`var`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#variable-declaration) is used here to initialize variables on the first bar only, which has the secondary effect of propagating their value from bar to bar.

We use twice ATR(7) here as the value subtracted from the `low` on entry and from the highest in-trade high after that.

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
entry = rising(close, 5)
myAtr = 2 * atr(7)

var inTrade = false
var float stop = na
var float inTradeHi = na
if entry and not inTrade
    // Enter.
    inTradeHi := high
    inTrade := true
    stop := low - myAtr
if inTrade
    if close < stop[1]
        // Exit.
        inTrade := false
    else
        // In a trade; update stop.
        inTradeHi := max(inTradeHi, high)
        stop := inTradeHi - myAtr

tradeEntry = not inTrade[1] and inTrade
tradeExit = inTrade[1] and not inTrade
plotchar(tradeEntry, "tradeEntry", "▲", location.belowbar, color.lime, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(tradeExit,  "tradeExit",  "▼", location.abovebar, color.fuchsia, size = size.tiny)
plot(inTrade ? stop : na, "Stop", color.fuchsia, 1, plot.style_circles)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much!)